# How to open Dropbox folder from a link in Trello?

Tags: trello, dropbox

I want to be able to add a Dropbox link to Trello and those people who have their Dropbox already synced should be able to click and open the file in system not in the browser. (Needed for both Windows & OS X.)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would expect that this isn't possible. You'd need to use the protocol format `file:///` to open a local file, and even then there's no guarantee that everyone has their Dropbox files in the same place on their local drive.

Comment: What about using somesort of IFTTT is it still not possible?